# Adding firebase is conflicting with google play services

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

Since adding Firebase to my application so I can send push notifications to users through appcenter I have encountered a number of problems.

I am currently experiencing a possible merging issue between two libraries.

```
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being 
requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but 
resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies 
tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

As you can see here I do not have any specific dependencies for play-services-basement...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.3.1'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxsoftware.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 36
        versionName "2.8.17"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    def appCenterSdkVersion = '1.9.0'

    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-push:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'
    implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:3.0.0'
    implementation 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:2.0.0'
}
```

I have ran the command ./gradlew :app:dependencies and it prints out:

```
* What went wrong:
Project 'app' not found in root project 'ChimePassportAndroid'.
```

Comment: Where in your code are you using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement`? Did you add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as the last line in your file?

Comment: @AlexMamo The weird thing is, that I am not using play-services-basement... I can do a global search for it and nothing appears, and I have applied the plugin at like 28 where I am applying my other plugins (Doesn't need to be at the bottom, just outside of the tags)

Comment: Yes, it should be the last line in your build.gradle file. Have you aslo try to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'`, in order to be able to use notifications?

Comment: @AlexMamo I left the plug-in where it is, but added the firebase-messaging library and it worked! Thank you for the help mate :). Ill have to message app center and tell them to fix their poop start up guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Firebase messaging, you need to add in your `build.gradle` file the corresponding dependency like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

And your problem will be solved.